# OEmbed from Pinterest

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, embed

I'm looking for a way to show a certain pinterest pinboard in a post.

I've found in the [WordPress.com Documentation](https://en.support.wordpress.com/embed-from-pinterest/) that you can simply post your pinboards URL there. This is not possible on a selfhosted Wordpress installation so I guess that is something specific to wordpress.com.

What would be the easiest way to add a URL Handler that translates the pinterest URL into the needed embed code and include the pinterest js file?

Comment: [Refer this][1]


  [1]: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-widgets/screenshots/

Comment: Yeah, those are widgets. But as far as I know widgets can't be embedded in a post (Only by using special "widgets in posts" plugins).

Comment: thanks @Karthikeyani for the hint with the widget. I tried it and it turned out it has the needed options. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Great!! Pls upvote my comment

Comment: .com uses oembed, you can add the code to enable pinterest oembed to a self hosted site too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-widgets actually has the needed functionality but doesn't mention it in the description.

After installing and activating you can add a pinboard to a post by using the following shortcodes

```
[pin_board url="http://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/pin-pets/"]
[pin_board url="http://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/pin-pets/" size="header"]
[pin_board url="http://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/pin-pets/" size="custom" image_width="100" board_width="900" board_height="450"]
```

more options can be found on the plugins "settings" page after installing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to Pinterest site and open a pin which you want to embed on your post. Now you can find **3 dots** near **send** button in the top of the pin. Click that dots and you can see "**Embed**" option. Now click that.

Pinterest will give you 5 options to embed their content.

1. Pin
2. Profile
3. Board
4. Follow
5. and Pin it button

Based on your requirement, select the option and scroll down. You can find embed code at the bottom of the page. Just copy and paste in your post.

**Note :** The script tag should be included once in a page.

Comment: yeah, that works if you don't use the visual editor. And you still need to include the javascript file in the footer.

Comment: However you are going to display single page at a time right? So no need to include in the footer. You can simply add the anchor tag and script tag in the post in WP admin panel in each pages.

Comment: yeah, but you still can't use the visual editor. it breaks the html. not suitable for my users.